# How to make a dropdown stay when processing different If/Else blocks?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to PHP-to-Mysql so I'm using the mysql_* function which others have stated to be unsupported anymore. But I find this place the best to ask my question since I can't find anyone with a similar question.

So basically, my problem is how to make a dropdown list stay which is inside an IF/ELSE block. When it is passes a value (submit) through another IF/ELSE block, it basically disappears so I'm trying a code where I don't have to re-write the entire dropdown code inside the next IF/ELSE block. Since what I'm trying is to show a textbox depending on what option is selected inside the dropdown (it has an auto-submit function). Is this possible? Or I have to resort to other libraries (jQuery,javascript etc.)?

Here's a part of the code if it helps:

```
elseif($_POST['question'] == edit ){
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT questionID FROM questions");

    echo "<form action='' method='post'>
    Edit Question No.
        <select name='question_select' onchange=this.form.submit()>
            <option  value=null selected>--</option>";

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                echo "<option value=\"".$row['questionID']."\">".$row['questionID']."</option>";
            }

    echo "</select></form>";
  }

//TEXTBOX TO BE DISPLAYED WHEN A NUMBER IS SELECTED IN EDIT EXISTING
if (isset($_POST['question_select'])){
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT question FROM questions WHERE questionID='{$_POST['question_select']}'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);     

    echo "Editing Question ",$_POST['question_select'],"<br>
    <form action='' method='post'>
        <textarea name='edited_question' rows='4' cols='50'>",$row['question'],"</textarea><br>
        <input type='submit' name='save' value='Save'>
        <input type='hidden' name='question_num' value='{$_POST['question_select']}'>
        <input type='submit' name='cancel' value='Cancel'>
    </form>";
}

//PASSING OF VALUES WHEN SAVE IS PRESSED
if (isset($_POST['save'])){
    $edited_question = trim($_POST['edited_question']);
    mysql_query("UPDATE questions SET question='$edited_question' WHERE questionID='{$_POST['question_num']}'") or die(mysql_error);
    header("Location:admin_questions.php");
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create functions http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php

Comment: @ Waqar Alamgir - Sorry, I'm kinda new to PHP so I'm not that familiar with functions. So basically, judging from functions, I have to create something (maybe a dropdown function) that I have to call on the dependent IF/ELSE blocks?

Comment: Yes create a function like "renderDropdown" that returns html which then be called in any if/else block!

Comment: Oh I see thank you! Maybe I'll have to study about it then. I think I should be asking in a forum instead of here lol.

Comment: see my answer, I have a demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function renderDropdown($res)
{
    echo "
    <select name='question_select' onchange=this.form.submit()>
        <option  value=null selected>--</option>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            echo "<option value=\"".$row['questionID']."\">".$row['questionID']."</option>";
        }
    echo "</select>";
}

if(1==1)
{
    echo "<form action='' method='post'>Edit If Question No.";
    renderDropdown($res);
    echo "</form>";
}
else
{
    // $someOtherRes
    echo "<form action='' method='post'>Edit Else Question No.";
    renderDropdown($someOtherRes);
    echo "</form>";
}
```

Comment: I've tried it but I'm getting an error. I'm not sure where to call the function, is it after every if statement? It's saying that it's undefined function.

Comment: define function into a file say functions.php include the file with include_once on top the page where you want to call it, then call this function on this page as many time you need.

Comment: Ok. So, it's more like a global declaration then? Guess that's why I'm getting an error. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm now that I've saved it as a functions.php file, how could I make it only appear once it's called? It appears immediately the moment the include() function is run...

Comment: use display:none and display:inline in style

Comment: Fixed it, found out I was using the wrong index when calling the function. Thanks for that though.

Answer (score 1):

use jquery for that.it is easy and simple to use.
for depanding dropdown,jquery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#abc").change(function()
    {
     var firstfeild= $("#firstfeild").val();
     $.post("getdata.php",{"firstfeild":firstfeild},function(data)
       {
        $("#abc").html(data);   
       });
   });
});
```

and in getdata.php, just write mysql query.